# docker compose multiple projects

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to set up local DOCKER env for multiple projects under the same network. I want to have the main docker-compose config file which will create Nginx proxy and PHP container. And many child docker-compose files with own Nginx. I want all child Nginx containers listen to the main PHP container. But for some reason, child Nginx containers failing with error `host not found in upstream "app-php" in /etc/nginx/vhost.d/site.cong25`

main `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app-nginx_proxy:
    build: ./nginx-proxy
    image: app/nginx-proxy:latest
    container_name: app-nginx_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - appnetwork
  app-php:
    image: app/php:latest
    container_name: app-php
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - app_volume:/var/www/
    networks:
      - appnetwork
volumes:
  app_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: bind
      device: "$PWD/../services"
      o: bind
networks:
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

and child `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app-admin-nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: app-admin/nginx:latest
    container_name: app-admin-nginx
    volumes:
      - app_admin_volume:/var/www/app-admin
    networks:
      appnetwork:
        aliases:
          - app-admin.v2.local
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app-admin.v2.local
volumes:
  app_admin_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: bind
      device: "$PWD/../services/app-admin"
      o: bind
networks:
  appnetwork:
    external: true
```

also, `site.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app-admin.v2.local;

    root /var/www/app-admin/web;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/abboom_admin_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/abboom_admin_access.log;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app-php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

If I move all configs to the single `docker-compose` file all is working fine, but it's not flexible to use a single file, as I want add the ability for developers to run only apps they need and not all the app we have

Comment: Have you tried with the following syntax : docker-compose -f path/to/first/yml/file -f path/to/second/yml/file up {container*}

Comment: Maybe you could also try with the `links` property : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links (ex: add links: - app-web in your app-admin-nginx service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main `nginx` container has dependency on `app-php` service. You need to start `app-php` before `nginx`.

You also need to make sure both the services run in same project so that they use same network. You can use `-p` option of docker-compose.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

> Usage:   docker-compose [-f ...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
>   docker-compose -h|--help
>
> Options:   -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose
>   file
>                                 (default: docker-compose.yml)
>   -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
>                                 (default: directory name)

You can also use custom network to start service from different compose files in same network.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Comment: Im starting docker-compose with app-php first and only after that I'm starting child containers, so at the moment when child nginx starting app-php is already up and running

Comment: Or you mean I need to change ordering in the main file, to have php before proxy? I do not think ordering matter here, but I'll try

Comment: Are you starting the child nginx in the same project as app-php? By default compose would start the services in separate namespace. Even though you are using `appnetwork` in both yaml file, during runtime they would be `projectname1_appnetwork` and `projectname2_appnetwork`. So  you need start the child nginx service in same namespace as app-php. You can use `-p` argument of docker-compose to set the project name. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

Comment: it's in the different directories, and yeah I also found that docker adding prefix to the container name, that why I specify ` container_name:` with that option is creating the container without that prefix. But let me try to use `-p`. I'll let you know, thanks

Comment: Great thank you, the issue really was in the network name. I set `container_name:` to prevent adding prefix to the containers, but I did not add `name` to the network. So I change `networks:
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge` to  `networks:
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge name: appnetwork`  and now it's working