# docker-compose unlink network from child containers when stopping parent containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-role

This is a continuation of my journey [of creating multiple docker projects dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657572/docker-compose-multiple-projects). I did not mention previously, to make this process dynamica as I want devs to specify what project they want to use, I'm using ansible to up local env.

**Logic is:**

1. running `ansible-playbook run.yml -e "{projectsList:
   ['app-admin']}"` - providing list of projects I want to start
2. stop existing main containers (in case they are running from the previous time)
3. Start the main containers
4. Depend on the provided list of projects run role tasks () I have a separate role for each supported project
5. stop the existing child project containers (in case they are running from the previous time)
6. start the child project containers
7. make some configuration depend on the role

And here is the issue (again) with the network, when I stop the main containers it's failing with a message:

> error while removing network: network appnetwork has active endpoints

it makes sense as child docker containers use the same network, but I do not see so far way to change ordering of tasks as I'm using the roles, so main docker tasks always running before role-specific tasks.

**main ansible file:**

```
---
#- import_playbook: './services/old.yml'
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    # add list of all supported projects, THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED FOREACH NEW PROJECT!
    supportedProjects: ['all', 'app-admin', 'app-landing']
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ansible_become_pass"
      prompt: "Sudo password"
      private: yes
  pre_tasks:
    # List of projects should be provided
    - fail: msg="List of projects you want to run playbook for not provided"
      when: (projectsList is not  defined) or (projectsList|length == 0)
    # Remove unsupported projects from list
    - name: Filter out not supported projects
      set_fact:
        filteredProjectsList: "{{ projectsList | intersect(supportedProjects) }}"
    # Check if any of projects exist after filtering
    - fail: msg="All project you provided not supported. Supported projects {{ supportedProjects }}"
      when: filteredProjectsList|length == 0
    # Always stop existing docker containers
    - name: stop existing common app docker containers
      docker_compose:
        project_src: ../docker/common/
        state: absent
    - name: start common app  docker containers like nginx proxy, redic, mailcatcher etc. (this can take a while if running by the first time)
      docker_compose:
        project_src: ../docker/common/
        state: present
        build: no
        nocache: no
    - name: Get www-data id
      command: docker exec app-php id -u www-data
      register: wwwid
    - name: Get current user group id
      command: id -g
      register: userid
    - name: Register user and www-data ids
      set_fact:
        userid: "{{userid.stdout}}"
        wwwdataid: "{{wwwid.stdout}}"
  roles:

    - { role: app-landing, when: '"app-landing" in filteredProjectsList or "all" in filteredProjectsList' }
    - { role: app-admin,  when:  ("app-admin" in filteredProjectsList) or ("all" in filteredProjectsList) }
```

and role example `app-admin/tasks/mian.yml`:

```
---
- name: Sync {{name}} with git (can take while to clone repo by the first time)
  git:
    repo: "{{gitPath}}"
    dest: "{{destinationPath}}"
    version: "{{branch}}"
- name: stop existing {{name}} docker containers
  docker_compose:
    project_src: "{{dockerComposeFileDestination}}"
    state: absent
- name: start {{name}} docker containers (this can take a while if running by the first time)
  docker_compose:
    project_src: "{{dockerComposeFileDestination}}"
    state: present
    build: no
    nocache: no
- name: Copy {{name}} env file
  copy:
    src: development.env
    dest: "{{destinationPath}}.env"
    force: no
- name: Set file permissions for local {{name}} project files
  command:  chmod -R ug+w {{projectPath}}
  become: yes
- name: Set execute permissions for local {{name}} bin folder
  command: chmod -R +x {{projectPath}}/bin
  become: yes
- name: Set user/group for {{name}} to {{wwwdataid}}:{{userid}}
  command: chown -R {{wwwdataid}}:{{userid}} {{projectPath}}
  become: yes
- name: Composer install for {{name}}
  command: docker-compose -f {{mainDockerComposeFileDestination}}docker-compose.yml exec -T app-php sh -c "cd {{containerProjectPath}} && composer install"
```

Maybe there is a way to somehow unlink the network if the main container stop. I thought when a child container network set like external:

```
networks:
  appnetwork:
    external: true
```

solves the issue, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick experiment with an external network:

**dc1/dc1.yml**

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    networks: 
      - an0

networks:
  an0:
    external: true
```

**dc2/dc2.yml**

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
    networks: 
      - an0

networks:
  an0:
    external: true
```

Starting and stopping:

```
$ docker network create -d bridge an0
1e07251e32b0d3248b6e70aa70a0e0d0a94e457741ef553ca5f100f5cec4dea3

$ docker-compose -f dc1/dc1.yml up -d
Creating dc1_nginx_1 ... done

$ docker-compose -f dc2/dc2.yml up -d
Creating dc2_redis_1 ... done

$ docker-compose -f dc1/dc1.yml down
Stopping dc1_nginx_1 ... done
Removing dc1_nginx_1 ... done
Network an0 is external, skipping

$ docker-compose -f dc2/dc2.yml down
Stopping dc2_redis_1 ... done
Removing dc2_redis_1 ... done
Network an0 is external, skipping
```

Comment: oh, so I need to set the network as external in all `docker-compoe` files, for some reason I thought one of them (main) should have network not as external.